# mqtt invalid payload content, ftp

Tags: mqtt

I'm trying to do something with MQTT ( mqtt-sn actually ) - and want to know what is the way to report errors.

When using a command/response like pattern over MQTT - how should response errors be reported?

- Example 1:  something like FTP over MQTT.

  - Host sends "delete filename" - how would I report "file not found"
- Example 2: Device has a configurable sensor.

  - Host sends "configure sensor: parameter 1 = A, parameter = "

**Question:** How do I report "invalid parameter value"?

I can certainly invent my own method, I'd rather not.

People who write python say something like: "the python way of doing that is ___"

The answer I am looking for is: "MQTT-ic way of doing command/response error reporting is: ______".

The current list of ERROR codes in the MQTT-SN spec is rather limited to exactly 1 error "invalid"

See:  http://www.mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf
Section 5.3.10, table 5.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is effectively just a message exchagne protocol -- it only concerns itself with how messages are emitted, routed, and received.

It's really up to the application implementer to specify what the underlying message format is and what the messages mean. Your messages could be a packed binary payload, or a JSON string payload -- MQTT doesn't preclude you from using either. So there isn't really an "MQTT-ic way" of achieving what you ask!

However, to actually perform the request/response messaging paradigm using MQTT, which is fundamentally a publish/subscribe protocol, is something that is specified by the standard, but formally only in MQTT 5. The standard [Section 4.10](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901252) might provide with an idea of how to implement this if your client library does not already provide it for you.

But note that this only describes how clients can associate a `request` message with its paired `response` message. The *application-level* logic you are asking about is not in scope of the MQTT standard.

Unless your application is particularly performance critical, I would suggest using JSON strings as the message payload.